# How to set map's language

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1, bing-maps

How can I set language on the Bing maps?
Here is my XAML:

```
   <Maps:Map Credentials="key"
                  Language="ru" Grid.Row="1"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  ZoomLevel = "7.5">
```

I was trying Language parameter, but the language didn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Culture parameter, not the Language parameter. This is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306047.aspx

Try the following:

```
<Maps:Map Credentials="key"
          Culture="ru" Grid.Row="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          ZoomLevel = "7.5">
```